# Help me make this post less opinion-based

Tags: discussion

My question: [What are some representative European news sources?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/54840/what-are-some-representative-european-news-sources)

When I wrote the question I think I phrased it in an opinion-based way. I believe this question and the answers provided can be made useful and factual by emphasizing that I'm looking for a **representative sample** of European news sources, but I'm new to the community and so I ask: would that be a direction the community would consider "fact-based"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with this question is that it is a [shopping question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

Who decides which news sources are "representative"? How would the author of an answer counter arguments that the sources they picked are too left or too right or too whatever else? Every medium has some political slant. That's impossible to avoid. But when does a medium gets too slanted to still be considered representative? That is completely subjective.

And Stack Exchange is generally not a good platform for subjective questions.

Comment: Thank you for this; I had not read about shopping questions. Is it worth turning the question into "How do I understand and choose news sources from a society that's not my own?", or should I make that a separate question?